# I am trying to display a paragraph of text in HTML but I need to create it as a JSON object and read it with AJAX to do so. My code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I have tried to iterate through the JSON object but it is not working. Is there a more efficient way to even structure the object? Also, I am not sure that the AJAX request is being made because I keep seeing an error message which is "There was a problem: 0".

This is my JS file:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "lab4.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){

            var message = "";
            
            $.each(responseData.text, function(i, item) {
                $.each(item.tutoring-text, function(x, s) {
                    message += s;  
                });     
            });  
            $("#tutoring-text").html(message);
        }, 
        error: function(msg) {
              // there was a problem
              alert("There was a problem: " + msg.status + " " + msg.statusText);
        }
      });
    
  });
```

This is my JSON file:

```js
{
    "text":{
        
        "tutoring-text": [
        
            "Gamma Nu Eta holds weekly tutoring sessions every Wednesday.",
            "At these tutoring sessions, GNH can help you with any course in your ITWS degree program.",
            "This includes ITWS core classes, such as Intro to ITWS and Web Systems, or classes outside of ITWS, such as Computer Science 1 and Data Structures.",
            "We can also help with any questions that you might have about career development, resumes, as well as just general questions about RPI."      
        ]  
        
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that images of code are one of the least helpful things to include in a question (and external links to primary information are also strongly discouraged).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This needs a `jquery` tag.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `tutoring-text` is `tutoring - text` - you can't use `-` in a variable.  Change to `$.each(item["tutoring-text"], function...`  and, as in the answer below, `.text` is not an array, so nothing to $.each on

Comment: `0 error` will also have an error message in the console.  Always look in the browser's console.  Most likely it will be `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///.../lab4.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.` - if it *is* this message then it's because you're trying to run ajax from a local file.  Your files *must* be provided by a server (on localhost is ok).

Comment: thank you sooo much, that is the message I am seeing in the console. How do I get the files on the server, could you elaborate a bit on that please?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to iterate when your JSON structure is reasonably flat.

All you really need is

```js
$("#tutoring-text").html(response.text["tutoring-text"].join(""))
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"?

Comment: It is still giving me an error and not printing the text I need.

Comment: Obvious question that you're forcing us to ask: *What's the error*

Comment: The error message that is in the code... I am not sure if the AJAX request is being made at all.